# Timestamp changes Date

Tags: java, android, mysql, date, datetime

I use the following server code to get a text representation of a Timestamp from a user before storing it in the DB.

```
    String timestampString = request.getParameter("timestamp");
    String timezoneID = request.getParameter("timezone");
    System.out.println(TAG + " newTestIdString: " + newTestIdString
              + "\n" + TAG + " timestampString: " + timestampString);

    Integer newTestId = Integer.parseInt(newTestIdString);

    try{
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezoneID));
        Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(timestampString);
        System.out.println(TAG + "timezone-JP: " + dateFormat.format(parsedDate));

        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        System.out.println(TAG + "timezone-UTC: " +   dateFormat.format(parsedDate));

        dateFormat.format(parsedDate);
        timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
        System.out.println(TAG + "timestamp: " + timestamp.toString());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However if the user sends data containing a Timestamp string at 7:29, I get the following output:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/17 18:29:59 | ProcessTest  newTestIdString: 1109
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/17 18:29:59 | ProcessTest  timestampString: 2015-09-18 07:29:58
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/17 18:29:59 | ProcessTest timezone-JP: 2015-09-18 07:29:58
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/17 18:29:59 | ProcessTest timezone-UTC: 2015-09-17 10:29:58
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/17 18:29:59 | ProcessTest timestamp: 2015-09-17 18:29:58.0
```

Why does the timestamp change the date in the last line?

How can I create a Timestamp with the UTC date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TimeStamp` or a `Date` doesn't have any timezone associated with it...

When you do `timestamp.toString()`, it gives a string representation of the Date in your **JVM's default timezone**.

If you wan't it in a particular timezone, just `format()` it as you did with other `Date` objects.

```
System.out.println(TAG + "timestamp: " + dateFormat.format(timestamp));
```

PS: `java.sql.Timestamp` extends `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Technically not your "system time zone", if you mean host OS time zone. The `toString` method on the old classes (java.util.Date, java.sql.Date, java.sql.Timestamp) apply your **JVM’s current default time zone** when generating the string representation of the date-time value. That current default time zone can be changed during runtime at any moment by any thread of any code of any app running in that same JVM.